# Typing a message to an offline user shows an error

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

When I write messages to a user who is offline - without sending it - I get an error

> Your message was not sent because of an error

User session not found - error code 503

[image: pick error]

response:

```xml
/http-bind/
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
  <message xml:lang='en' xmlns='jabber:client'
      to='abogdanov@bingo-dev.ru/181473147433257603378'
      from='jabberadmin@bingo-dev.ru'
      type='error'>
    <paused xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/>
    <error code='503' type='cancel'>
      <service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
      <text xml:lang='en' xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>
        User session not found
      </text>
    </error>
  </message>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client is trying to send "typing notifications" to indicate user you are typing, and doesn't handle errors well: it should not show errors for typing notifications (or not send it to offline at all?). Also, you may have disabled offline storage at your server and that is why server report errors.